# Unable to resolve Firestore dependency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fitness.perspactive"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my project gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In my application I used Firebase realtime database. Later on, when I also tried to include cloud Firestore, it isn't syncing.

When I tried to sync it, it shows:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.2.1

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct version to use for the recently launched beta of Cloud Firestore is 11.4.2. You can declare a dependency on it like so:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
```

All Firebase components should be at the same version so, in your case that would be

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
```

Make sure you have the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager, otherwise you won't be able to find this version either :-).

While you're at it you'll need to upgrade to the latest google-services plugin, version 3.1.1.

All of this and more are [documented on the setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). It's worth going through that step by step and checking that your project has all those things even if you have an existing Firebase-enabled app.

Answer (score 0):

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
make sure that your com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2 is meeting the same version preferred by https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup