# Can't import “import com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges” original question still has no answers

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I almost have the same problem as this question but it has no answers.
[Can't import "import com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961592/cant-import-import-com-google-firebase-firestore-metadatachanges)

I am following the codes here at https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5086986-create-a-scalable-and-powerful-backend-for-android-using-firebase-in-java/5769306-implement-a-chat-room

Error log

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/MetadataChanges;
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java:86)
        at com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat.MentorChatActivity.generateOptionsForAdapter(MentorChatActivity.java:126) //blue highlighted
        at com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat.MentorChatActivity.configureRecyclerView(MentorChatActivity.java:112)//blue highlighted
        at com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat.MentorChatActivity.onCreate(MentorChatActivity.java:57)//blue highlighted
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sp.firestorechat-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sp.firestorechat-2/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions$Builder.setQuery(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.java:86) 
        at com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat.MentorChatActivity.generateOptionsForAdapter(MentorChatActivity.java:126) 
        at com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat.MentorChatActivity.configureRecyclerView(MentorChatActivity.java:112) 
        at com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat.MentorChatActivity.onCreate(MentorChatActivity.java:57) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sp.firestorechat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2"
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    //GLIDE
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //BUTTERKNIFE
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'


    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.1.1'
    
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

chat activity

```
package com.sp.firestorechat.mentor_chat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.sp.firestorechat.Message;
import com.sp.firestorechat.MessageHelper;
import com.sp.firestorechat.R;
import com.sp.firestorechat.User;
import com.sp.firestorechat.UserHelper;
import com.sp.firestorechat.base.BaseActivity;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MentorChatActivity extends BaseActivity implements MentorChatAdapter.Listener {

    // FOR DESIGN
    // 1 - Getting all views needed
    @BindView(R.id.activity_mentor_chat_recycler_view) RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.activity_mentor_chat_text_view_recycler_view_empty)
    TextView textViewRecyclerViewEmpty;
    @BindView(R.id.activity_mentor_chat_message_edit_text)
    TextInputEditText editTextMessage;
    @BindView(R.id.activity_mentor_chat_image_chosen_preview)
    ImageView imageViewPreview;

    // FOR DATA
    // 2 - Declaring Adapter and data
    private MentorChatAdapter mentorChatAdapter;
    @Nullable
    private User modelCurrentUser;
    private String currentChatName;

    // STATIC DATA FOR CHAT (3)
    private static final String CHAT_NAME_ANDROID = "android";
    private static final String CHAT_NAME_BUG = "bug";
    private static final String CHAT_NAME_FIREBASE = "firebase";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.configureRecyclerView(CHAT_NAME_ANDROID);
        this.configureToolbar();
        this.getCurrentUserFromFirestore();
    }

    @Override
    public int getFragmentLayout() { return R.layout.activity_mentor_chat; }

    // --------------------
    // ACTIONS
    // --------------------

    @OnClick(R.id.activity_mentor_chat_send_button)
    public void onClickSendMessage() { }

    @OnClick({ R.id.activity_mentor_chat_android_chat_button, R.id.activity_mentor_chat_firebase_chat_button, R.id.activity_mentor_chat_bug_chat_button})
    public void onClickChatButtons(ImageButton imageButton) {
        // 8 - Re-Configure the RecyclerView depending chosen chat
        switch (Integer.valueOf(imageButton.getTag().toString())){
            case 10:
                this.configureRecyclerView(CHAT_NAME_ANDROID);
                break;
            case 20:
                this.configureRecyclerView(CHAT_NAME_FIREBASE);
                break;
            case 30:
                this.configureRecyclerView(CHAT_NAME_BUG);
                break;
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.activity_mentor_chat_add_file_button)
    public void onClickAddFile() { }

    // --------------------
    // REST REQUESTS
    // --------------------
    // 4 - Get Current User from Firestore
    private void getCurrentUserFromFirestore(){
        UserHelper.getUser(getCurrentUser().getUid()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                modelCurrentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            }
        });
    }

    // --------------------
    // UI
    // --------------------
    // 5 - Configure RecyclerView with a Query
    private void configureRecyclerView(String chatName){
        //Track current chat name
        this.currentChatName = chatName;
        //Configure Adapter & RecyclerView
        this.mentorChatAdapter = new MentorChatAdapter(generateOptionsForAdapter(MessageHelper.getAllMessageForChat(this.currentChatName)), Glide.with(this), this, this.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        mentorChatAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mentorChatAdapter.getItemCount()); // Scroll to bottom on new messages
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(this.mentorChatAdapter);
    }

    // 6 - Create options for RecyclerView from a Query
    private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Message> generateOptionsForAdapter(Query query){
        return new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Message>()
                .setQuery(query, Message.class)
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .build();
    }

    // --------------------
    // CALLBACK
    // --------------------

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        // 7 - Show TextView in case RecyclerView is empty
        textViewRecyclerViewEmpty.setVisibility(this.mentorChatAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

these 3 lines of code is the error

```
.setQuery(query, Message.class)

this.mentorChatAdapter = new MentorChatAdapter(generateOptionsForAdapter(MessageHelper.getAllMessageForChat(this.currentChatName)), Glide.with(this), this, this.getCurrentUser().getUid());

this.configureRecyclerView(CHAT_NAME_ANDROID);
```

Comment: Does this help you https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607624/unable-to-resolve-firestore-dependency  ,

Comment: Can you see that the `MetadataChanges.class` exists from the IDE? Also verify it's inside the package `com.google.firebase.firestore`

Comment: sorry how do i check if the Metadatachanges.class exists from the IDE and verify if its iniside? can you guide me or is there a post here explaining how to do that. sorry i am new to android studio - jms

Comment: the links you gave me does not work - susan

Comment: The current latest version of [firestore is 22.1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries), not 22.0.2. Also the firebase-core library is no longer required. Have you tried using [firebase-bom](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) to handle the library versions?